# Using Legacy router while offering API access for own component

Tags: router, api

I think this could be a bit complicated. I have a non namespaced Joomla 4 component, but i need to have an API access for specific data.
So i created a `/src` directory in Backend with all needed structures for calling data over one model.
Also I created ecerything needed in the `/api` folder like controller, model, serializer etc.

Everything works fine. The component still works in front and backend. That's because a I use the LegacyComponent for everything except API access.

Here is the `\administrator\components\com_mycom\src\Extension\MycomComponent.php`

```
<?php

namespace Maidan\Component\Mycomp\Administrator\Extension;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLRegistryAwareTrait;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Joomla\CMS\Extension\ComponentInterface;
use Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\DispatcherInterface;
use Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplicationInterface;
use Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcherFactoryInterface;
use Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\LegacyComponentDispatcher;

// phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
\defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;
// phpcs:enable PSR1.Files.SideEffects

class MycompComponent implements ComponentInterface
{
    use HTMLRegistryAwareTrait;

    private $dispatcherFactory;

    public function __construct(ComponentDispatcherFactoryInterface $dispatcherFactory)
    {
        $this->dispatcherFactory = $dispatcherFactory;
    }

    public function getDispatcher(CMSApplicationInterface $application): DispatcherInterface
    {
        if ($application->isClient('api')) {
            return $this->dispatcherFactory->createDispatcher($application);
        } else {
            return new LegacyComponentDispatcher($application);
        }
    }

    public function boot(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
    }

    public function validateSection($section, $item = null)
    {
        return;
    }

    public function getContexts(): array
    {
        Factory::getLanguage()->load('com_mycomp', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);

        $contexts = [];

        return $contexts;
    }
}
```

The only problem I have is that the legacy router for the frontend is not getting used anymore.

How can i tell the framework to use that router (`\components\com_mycomp\router.php`) for all legacy access in the frontend?

#### Update

Looks like this approach works. Legacy router is getting used again, but please let me know if it could cause trouble. I updated the ServerProvider like this:

```
return new class () implements ServiceProviderInterface {
    public function register(Container $container)
    {
        $app  = Factory::getApplication();
        if ($app->isClient('api')) {
            $container->registerServiceProvider(new MVCFactory('\\Maidan\\Component\\Mycomp'));
            $container->registerServiceProvider(new ComponentDispatcherFactory('\\Maidan\\Component\\Mycomp'));

            $container->set(
                ComponentInterface::class,
                static function (Container $container) {
                    $component = new MycompComponent($container->get(ComponentDispatcherFactoryInterface::class));
                    $component->setRegistry($container->get(Registry::class));

                    return $component;
                }
            );
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the component implement `Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterServiceInterface`. Create and return the router instance in the `createRouter()` method:

```
public function createRouter(\Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplicationInterface $application, \Joomla\CMS\Menu\AbstractMenu $menu): \Joomla\CMS\Component\Router\RouterInterface
{
    \JLoader::register('MycompRouter', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_mycomp/router.php');

    return new \MycompRouter($application, $menu);
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Will try it out tomorrow. Please let me know what you think of my update to the question.

Comment: It's no good. Component definition should not change depending on application. Building frontend URLs should be possible from any application.

Comment: Right, so even if API data would need an SEF URL, your approach would work, right?

Comment: Yes, that should work.